# How to call function in Go file from command line

Tags: go

I have 2 go files:

```
main.go
otherFile.go
```

Inside of 'main.go' I have a 'main' function and I can call it from the command line like this:

```
go run main.go
```

So far so good.

Inside of 'otherFile' I can't have another 'main' function so I have a function called 'otherFunction'.

How can I call this function in 'otherFile.go' from the command line, similarly to how I did 'go run main.go'?

I don't necessarily want main.go to run, or call 'otherFunction' from 'main.go' by importing it, etc.

Is this possible or am I thinking about it in the wrong way? I am new to Go so still trying to figure out some of the basic concepts.

Thanks.

Comment: This question was flagged as 'This question already has an answer here' however I reviewed the suggested 'duplicate' question and found that it was unrelated to the question I am asking here. Thanks.

Comment: you can't invoke just any function from the command line.  `main` is always the entrypoint of the Go program and you'll hve to invoke `otherFunction` from there if you want it to run.  The linked question is relevant because you need to compile both source files, not just `main.go`.

Comment: Got it. This was the clarification I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry for the close, I misread your question. Anyway, you can't do what you want.

Comment: Never use go run with filename arguments.

Comment: Thanks for reopening. Yeah, got it. Go isn't intended to work that way - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do what you want, if you structure your project along these lines:

- `/path/to/project/root/`

  - `apps/`

    - `an-app/`

      - `main.go`
    - `another-app/`

      - `main.go`
  - `package1/`
  - `package2/`
  - `package3/`
  - . . .

where `apps/an-app` and `apps/another-app` are your commands that you want to run, and `package1`, `package2`, and `package3` are shared packages that are imported by the apps.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually exactly what I ended up doing - creating more separate folders each with one 'main.go' file.

Answer (score 0):

in the `otherFile.go` define a different `package` name. like:

```
package otherFile
```

Add the `main()` func, then run the function you want inside that `main()` func.
From the terminal, you run `go run otherFile.go`.

The package system is different from what other languages have. But you'll get the idea if you keep using them.

Comment: I appreciate the response. Yeah exactly I'm just still used to thinking in terms of Javascript and Python where this works a little differently. I'm definitely learning a lot.